# Is returning a string literal address from a function safe and portable?

Tags: c++, string

I need a function to return a string that will only be accessed read-only. The string contents is known at compile time so that I will use a string literal anyway.

I can return something like `std::string`:

```
std::string myFunction()
{
   return "string";
}
```

or return `const char*`:

```
const char* myFunction()
{
   return "string";
}
```

Is the second alternative safe and portable in this scenario?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> Is the second alternative safe and portable in this scenario?

**Yes!** The storage allocation of string literals is **static** and they persist for the lifetime of the application.

Comment: Could you supply a reference for your proof?

Answer (score 11):

Yes! But beware of this potential gotcha:

```
char * myFunc() {
    return "Constant string?";
}
```

Yes, you can convert a string literal to a *non-const* `char *`! This will enable you to later break the world by trying to modify the contents of that `char *`. This "feature" exists for legacy reasons -- string literals are older than const, and were originally defined as `char *` in C.

g++ throws out an obnoxious warning for this, even in the default mode, thankfully. I don't know if VC++ throws out a warning just as eagerly.

Comment: @Philip: I tried this out in VS2008 and I got no warning.  I don't know if there is a warning for this.  Maybe there is and its turned off by default because so much of the supplied headers would trigger the warning ;-)

Answer (score 3):

Yes.  (It isn't different of storing such pointer in a global data structure).