# Is c_str() on a concatenated string literal safe?

Tags: c++, string, std, c-strings

I know from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2371698/1531708) that string literals are allocated statically. But is the following string concatenation also safe to use?

```
void someFunction(std::string& foo) {
    functionTakingCString(("start " + foo + " end").c_str());
}
```

**Follow Up Question**: As stated in the comments, this would be indeed unsafe when functionTakingCString would store that pointer. In this case, would the following be valid:

```
void someFunction(std::string& foo) {
    std::string bar = "start " + foo + " end";
    functionTakingCString(bar.c_str());
}
```

Comment: As long as `functionTakingCString` doesn't store that pointer and something tries to use it beyond the lifetime of the temporary `std::string`.

Comment: thanks for the comment - I added a follow up question regarding your advice

Comment: `bar`s lifetime would end at the `}` anyway so it's basically the same issue in your examples.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The concatenated string is only allocated while `functionTakingCString(("start " + foo + " end").c_str());` is running. Then the memory is deallocated and that pointer is no longer safe to use as you can read [here](http://www.bogotobogo.com/cplusplus/memoryallocation.php). If that pointer is passed to anything that runs after `functionTakingCString` exits then you will have trouble.